# Can't provide NuGet package source credentials to Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an Azure function which has a dependency on a private package feed.

I am copying a `nuget.config` file to the app service which looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyPackageFeed" value="<package feed path>" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
  <MyPackageFeed>
    <add key="Username" value="<first part of Hotmail address, before @ symbol>" />
    <add key="Password" value="<newly generated access token for username>" />
  </MyPackageFeed>
</packageSourceCredentials>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

**Note:** I use the first part of my Hotmail account email address as this is the username I use to authenticate to the private feed elsewhere - Visual Studio etc.

This is what I am seeing in the Logs in the Azure function portal:

```
2016-10-05T11:57:16.974 Restoring packages.
2016-10-05T11:57:16.974 Starting NuGet restore
2016-10-05T11:57:18.381 Restoring packages for D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerSqlDb\project.json...
2016-10-05T11:57:19.322 Unable to load the service index for source <path to feed>
2016-10-05T11:57:19.322 The parameter is incorrect.
```

If I change the `Password` key to `ClearTextPassword` as suggested by @brettsam, I now get the following:

```
2016-10-05T14:03:04.479 Please provide credentials for: <path to feed>
2016-10-05T14:03:05.097 Unable to load the service index for source <path to feed>
2016-10-05T14:03:05.097 Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
2016-10-05T14:03:05.142 UserName: Password:
```

Comment: Is the `Password` value that you got above the token that you got directly from your feed? Or did you generate it with `nuget.exe sources add|update` on your local machine?

Comment: @brettsam I generated the token from the `Team Services` online portal

Comment: You can try to create an alternative credential on VSTS, then add your feed source by using nuget.exe sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {alternative user name} -password {your PAT} command. On the other hand It seems that the issue is not related to credential (unable to load the service index for source), what're detail steps to create and user Azure function?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try using `key="ClearTextPassword"` (instead of `key="Password"`). If you use `Password`, NuGet assumes the value is encrypted and will try to decrypt it.

For example, I created a package feed in VSTS, then created a personal access token and used this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyPrivateFeed" value="https://brettsam.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/stackoverflow/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyPrivateFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="brettsam" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{PAT}" />
    </MyPrivateFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I just tried this myself and it worked. Can you re-post exactly what your nuget.config looks like above? And double-check that your PAT has all the correct 'Packaging read' permissions? Ultimately this is a nuget config issue not entirely related to Azure Functions, so you should be able to set this up locally on your machine and test it out more quickly than doing it through the Functions sites. That may help you narrow it down.

Comment: Looks like I had an issue creating the PAT, thanks for all your help

Comment: how to encrypt the PAT value?

Comment: @Vista check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77155887/3088349

Answer (score 4):

A better way IMO to achieve this.

The answer above is not wrong, it works. The only issue is that the PAT key is exposed.

You can use the NuGet command line to do the job for you.

If you do not have NuGet cli, [install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297784/3088349) it or use dotnet cli (check below).

Then you can run the following command that will add Azure DevOps feed and it will automatically encrypt the password inside NuGet.Config.

```
nuget sources add -name <Feed_Name> -source <Feed_URL> -username <Any_String_But_Not_Null> -password <Personal_Access_Token>
```

or with dotnet CLI:

```
dotnet nuget add source <Feed_URL> -n <Feed_Name> -u <Any_String_But_Not_Null> -p <Personal_Access_Token>
```

When you check your NuGet.Config file now, you will find out that it has added an encrypted password instead of the clear-text password.

username is typically your organization name and the password is your PAT in Azure DevOps.
[image]

> Note: as mentioned in the note, "Encrypted passwords are only supported on Windows, and only can be decrypted when used on the same machine and via the same user as the original encryption." [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials).

Ref:

- [How to install NuGet cli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297784/3088349)
- [How to add NuGet resources with credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=azure-devops#legacy-project-setup-nuget-v2)
- [Where to find my NuGet.Config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#additional-user-wide-configuration)

Comment: As it turns out you do not need to install the nuget cli. You can perform this task using the `dotnet` command tool

`dotnet nuget sources add -name <Feed_Name> -source <Feed_URL> -username <Any_String_But_Not_Null> -password <Personal_Access_Token>`

Comment: It appears that nuget encrypts the password using an encryption key that is **unique to that machine**. I tried checking the nuget.config into source control and nuget would not restore on a different machine. I updated the config file with the same password on this different machine, and nuget generated a different sequence of characters.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials

"Encrypted passwords are only supported on Windows, and only can be decrypted when used on the same machine and via the same user as the original encryption."