# NuGet.Config file with custom source Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have a custom source feed for nuget I am trying to set up with my azure function. However I can't seem to make it work.

[image: The image posted shows the file folder of the azure function]

This image shows the files associated with the Function

[image]

The second shows how the config file is formatted. The blue lines represent the custom source name and url. Am I doing this right? If not, what should I do differently?

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Do you have any errors in portal logs during NuGet restore?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add credentials for your custom source feed.

Example here:
[Can't provide NuGet package source credentials to Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873563/cant-provide-nuget-package-source-credentials-to-azure-function)

Comment: Okay. I'll double check that. The file location of the NuGet.Config is correct though?

Comment: Yes. You can place a nuget.config file with your custom sources either in your function folder or in the Function App root (where it will be used for all functions)