# Unable to load the service index for source error for a private Azure DevOps NuGet feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm having an issue getting access to our private NuGet packages hosted on Azure DevOps for a new developer:

`error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/_packaging/CompanyPackages/nuget/v3/index.json`

I have generated a PAT from DevOps and modified the NuGet.config file. We have been using private NuGet feeds from DevOps for a year or two and I noticed Microsoft recently changed their billing model for Azure Artifacts so I'm wondering if this is part of the issue.

[image]
[image]

Do I need to opt in the new storage model for this new developer to be able to access the private NuGet feed or is there a way to attach a "Package Management" license to this new user?

Comment: What ended up being the underlying culprit ?

Comment: @jbooker I think the password had issues:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873563/cant-provide-nuget-package-source-credentials-to-azure-function/39875460#39875460

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't sound license-related. We've removed all license checks in Artifacts (so, no need to assign one to your new developer) and you're under the free tier limit of 2 GB (so, anyone in your organization with permissions to a feed should be able to access it).

Since it's a brand-new PAT, it shouldn't be expired (my first thought). But, some other things to try:

- Check that the user for whom you generated a PAT has [permissions to the feed they want to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops)
- Ensure that the PAT you generated is either all-scopes or includes either the Package (Read) or Package (Read, Write) scopes

Comment: Thanks. I think it was a combination of a permissions issue and this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39875460/1193140.