# Dotnet Build using Command Line and Update Nuget Packages

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, build, nuget

I have several web api solutions that I work on. They are built using ASP.Net Core.
I'm trying to build a powershell script that will pull down the latest version of the develop branch of each solution.
I would like to build the solution too. All of our nuget packages are in Azure.
When it builds the solution, it tries to update the nuget packages. How can I include, in the script, the credentials to the Azure nuget feed?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/consuming-packages-authenticated-feeds#credentials-in-environment-variables - it gives a number of options that might be suitable...

Answer (score 0):

To incorporate credentials for the Azure NuGet feed within your PowerShell script, you can utilize the **`NuGet.exe`** command-line tool alongside a **`NuGet.config`** file. :-

**`Nuget.config with Nuget credentials:-`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyPackageFeed" value="<package feed path>" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
  <MyPackageFeed>
    <add key="Username" value="<Email address, before @ symbol>" />
    <add key="Password" value="<New PAT or Access Token token for username>" />
  </MyPackageFeed>
</packageSourceCredentials>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Reference [SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873563/cant-provide-nuget-package-source-credentials-to-azure-function)

My Azure Repository with **`Nuget.config and Nuget.exe`**:-

[image]

***Powershell script:-***

```
# Path to NuGet.exe
$nugetExe = "PATH_TO_NUGET_EXE\nuget.exe"

# Path to your solution directory
$solutionDirectory = "PATH_TO_SOLUTION_DIRECTORY"

# Restore packages
& $nugetExe restore $solutionDirectory\YourSolution.sln -ConfigFile NuGet.config

# Build the solution
dotnet build $solutionDirectory\YourSolution.sln -c Debug -o $solutionDirectory\buildOutput
```

***For Azure DevOps:-***

```
$nugetExe = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\<if-anyfolder>\nuget.exe"

# Path to your solution/sln directory
$solutionDirectory = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.sln


& $nugetExe restore $solutionDirectory\YourSolution.sln -ConfigFile NuGet.config

dotnet build $solutionDirectory\YourSolution.sln -c Debug -o $solutionDirectory\buildOutput
```